# C# Detect textBox in KeyPress Event From Multiple textBoxes

Tags: c#

I have 5 textBoxes which access the same `KeyPressEvent()`
How do I detect from which textBox Currently key is Pressed ?

```
 private void textBox_Department_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

       e.Handled = !(Char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) | e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back | e.KeyChar==(char)Keys.Space);
    }
```

Comment: Cast the sender as a TextBox and evaluate the name to determine which text box the event was invoked from: `(TextBox)sender.Name`

Answer (score 1):

In the event signature, the 
`object sender` 
is the object (in your case TextBox) that invokes the KeyPress event.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `Tag` property or even use `x:Name` and check if `sender` is equal to it.

For example, if you were to use tag, you could do this to your `TextBox`es.

```
<TextBox Tag="textBox1"../>
```

then in your code, you can cast `sender` to `TextBox` and check if it's tag is equal to whatever you want.

```
var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
if(textBox.Tag == "textBox1"){}
```

Or even better, check the sender itself:

```
var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
if(textBox == myTextBoxNameInXName){}
```